# How to run a dynamic sql for each row of a table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, function, dynamic-sql, sp-executesql

I have a table which contains a column named `WhereClause`

```
DECLARE @UserGroups TABLE (WhereClause nvarchar(1000), totalCount int)
```

The table has been populated with some values for `WhereClause` but none for `totalCount` column.

An example of the `WhereClause` is "FirstName is null".

Basically for each row in the table, I'd need to calculate the COUNT(*) from another table (Users) and set the `totalCount` on the above table.

The below doesn't work:

```
SELECT UG.WhereClause, U.TotalCount
FROM @UserGroups as UG
OUTER APPLY (SELECT COUNT(*) as 'TotalCount' FROM [Users] WHERE UG.WhereClause)
) U
```

I tried creating a sql function and calling exec sp_executesql within the function but it's not supported.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_UserGroupCount]
(   
    @whereClause as NVARCHAR(1000)
)
RETURNS @returnValue TABLE (TotalCount INT)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @stmt nvarchar(1500)

    SET @stmt = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[Users]
    WHERE '  + @whereClause

    Exec sp_executesql @stmt

RETURN
END

SELECT * FROM [dbo].[fn_UserGroupCount]('Subject is null')
```

How would that be possible to populate my `@UserGroups` table as mentioned?

Thanks

Comment: Indeed the idea looks nice but this approach will add to processing overload as the D-SQL will have to be executed **for each row**. Can you find another alternative for your requirement?

Answer (score 4):

Try this, you'll have to use temporary table for dynamic SQL to be able to reach it (`@UserGroups` won't work so I replaced it with `#UserGroups`):

```
CREATE TABLE #UserGroups (WhereClause nvarchar(1000), totalCount int)
INSERT #UserGroups VALUES ('FirstName IS NULL', NULL)
INSERT #UserGroups VALUES ('FirstName IS NOT NULL', NULL)

DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(8000) = STUFF(
(
SELECT  ';UPDATE #UserGroups SET totalCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Users] WHERE ' + WhereClause + ') WHERE WhereClause = ''' + WhereClause + ''''
FROM    #UserGroups
FOR XML PATH('')
), 1, 1, '')

PRINT @sql
EXEC(@sql)

SELECT  *
FROM    #UserGroups

DROP TABLE #UserGroups
```

However, problems might arise if `WhereClause` contains quotes, something like `FirstName LIKE 'Joe'`.

Comment: Thanks but I can't use it since it's not thread-safe. If 2 calls are made at the same time, it fails with temp tables.

Comment: You're welcome. Do you get some error? What does the error text say? Do you call this code from application?

Comment: I had a different issue but this answer gave me the clue I needed to fix it! thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I would use a cursor to build a string containing your update statements with the select count(*) from @whereclause built in. You can then execute this to perform your updates. See the SQLFiddle below:

**UPDATED** Now works where the where clause has single quotes in it and also apostrophes in where clauses

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b1691/1)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
create table users
(
  userid int primary key identity,
  name varchar(50),
  subject varchar(50) null
);

INSERT INTO users (name, subject)
VALUES
    ('Fred', 'Maths'),
    ('Bill', null),
    ('Helen', 'English'),
    ('O''Keefe', 'Maths');
```

**Query 1**:

```
DECLARE @WhereClause nvarchar(1000)
DECLARE @stmt nvarchar(1500) = ''

CREATE TABLE #UserGroups (WhereClause nvarchar(1000), totalCount int)
INSERT #UserGroups VALUES ('Subject IS NULL', NULL)
INSERT #UserGroups VALUES ('Subject IS NOT NULL', NULL)
INSERT #UserGroups VALUES ('Subject =''Maths''', NULL)
INSERT #UserGroups VALUES ('name =''O''''Keefe''', NULL)

DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
  SELECT WhereClause FROM #UserGroups

OPEN cur

FETCH cur  INTO @WhereClause

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

  SELECT @stmt = @stmt + 
      'UPDATE #UserGroups ' +
      'SET totalCount = ' +
      '(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE ' + @WhereClause + ') ' +
      'WHERE WhereClause = ''' + REPLACE(@WhereClause, '''', '''''') + ''';' 
  FETCH cur  INTO @WhereClause
END

CLOSE cur
DEALLOCATE cur

--select @stmt
exec(@stmt)

SELECT *
FROM #UserGroups

DROP TABLE #UserGroups
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b1691/1/0)**:

```
|         WHERECLAUSE | TOTALCOUNT |
------------------------------------
|     Subject IS NULL |          1 |
| Subject IS NOT NULL |          3 |
|    Subject ='Maths' |          2 |
|    name ='O''Keefe' |          1 |
```

Comment: That dynamic SQL isn't safe if `WhereClause` might include quotes. The `COUNT()` query is safe, but the comparison back to the `WhereClause` column isn't.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever updated so it handles quotes in the where clause. Might still have a problem with where clauses which have quotes in the comparison value e.g. name='O''Keefe'

Comment: @TheLight This should now work for you for all whereclauses with apostrophes and text field comparisons

Comment: I like to pretend that the `CURSOR` command does not exist unless I'm going to update the rows being iterated.  I believe a simple while loop would do.